# Error on converting js function to kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I found a solution for prioritize an items list accoding by user preference in javascript at link: http://jsfiddle.net/fq3sy/1/

I'm trying to pass it to **kotlin**, but the list items sometimes are coming with same values for user chooses

**My Kotlin code currently:**

```
var arr = arrayOf("finish homework", "finish chores", "go shopping")
insertionSort(arr)

fun promptInput(str1: String, str2: String): String{
    println(str1+ " or " + str2 + "?");
    return str1
}

fun insertionSort(arr: Array<String>){
    println("arr size")
    //alert(insertionSort("What needs to be done first", ["finish homework", "finish chores", "go shopping"]));
    var len = arr.size
    var i = -1
    var j: Int? = null
    var tmp: String?

    while (len!=0) {
        tmp = arr[++i];
        j = i
        while (j!=0 && (promptInput(arr[j], tmp) == arr[j])) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--
        }
        arr[j + 1] = tmp;
        len--
    }
    return arr.reverse();
}
```

It is printing in kotlin:

```
I/System.out: arr size
I/System.out: finish homework or finish homework?
I/System.out: finish homework or finish homework?
```

**But it should print:**

```
I/System.out: arr size
I/System.out: finish homework or finish chores?
I/System.out: finish homework or go shopping?
I/System.out: finish chores or go shopping?
```

with the following order: finish homework,finish chores,go shopping

What I'm doing wrong in this conversion?

Comment: You replaced `j--` by `j!=0`, so you are using the wrong value of `j` in `arr[j + 1] = arr[j];` before updating it in `j--`. [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. The JS code could also use `Array.prototype.sort` directly rather than implementing its own sort function. Not sure about Kotlin.

Comment: @user4642212 kotlin doesn't support j-- as condition in while, cause it returns an integer and not a boolean, I've tried with j>0 and j!=0

Comment: Yes, but I’m certain that Kotlin supports _placing the `j--` statement at the correct position_ or at least using `j - 1`.

Comment: @user4642212 before I post here, I wrote the **j--** before **arr[j + 1] = arr[j]** too

Comment: @user4642212   j - 1  doesn't work too in while

Comment: Your code also uses the same `promptInput(comparison, arr[j], tmp) == arr[j]` condition without the updated `j`. You’re not using the decremented `j`. Replace all uses of `j` by `j - 1` or place `j--` before using the decremented `j` — whichever is possible. _“j - 1 doesn't work too in while”_ — `promptInput(arr[j - 1], tmp) == arr[j - 1]` does _not_ work?! What exactly did you try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221101/discussion-between-alexandre-martins-montebelo-and-user4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin as of strict type-system would not allow Ints to be 0 or anything as false or true. If you want Boolean, you can use `j-- != 0`.

You can do your work as follows:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val arr = arrayOf("finish homework", "finish chores", "go shopping")
    val result = insertionSort("What needs to be done first", arr)
    println(result.toList())
}

fun promptInput(comparison: String, str1: String, str2: String): String {
    println("$comparison: $str1 or $str2?");
    return readLine()!!
}

fun insertionSort(comparison: String, arr: Array<String>): Array<String> {
    println("arr size: ${arr.size}")
    var len = arr.size
    var i = -1
    var j: Int
    var tmp: String

    while (len-- != 0) {
        tmp = arr[++i];
        j = i
        while (j-- != 0 && (promptInput(comparison, arr[j], tmp) == arr[j])) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        arr[j + 1] = tmp
    }

    return arr.apply { reverse() }
}
```

With following ouput/input cases:

```
arr size: 3
What needs to be done first: finish homework or finish chores?
>> finish homework
What needs to be done first: finish homework or go shopping?
>> finish homework
What needs to be done first: finish chores or go shopping?
>> finish chores
[finish homework, finish chores, go shopping]
```

Comment: do you know a function to substitute the js prompt in kotlin?